# Get all columns of table and replace one column with value from CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1d3a42ad8feb49a68e9ffd571fe99421)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    product VARCHAR(255),
    supplier VARCHAR(255),
    customer VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(campaign, product, supplier, customer, quantity
)
VALUES 
("C001", "Product_A", "Supplier_01", "Customer_AY", "100"),
("C001", "Product_A", "Supplier_02", "Customer_BY", "300"),
("C001", "Product_B", "Supplier_01", "Customer_CY", "700"),

("C002", "Product_A", "Supplier_01", "Customer_DY", "500"),
("C002", "Product_B", "Supplier_01", "Customer_BY", "900"),

("C003", "Product_A", "Supplier_01", "Customer_AY", "600"),
("C003", "Product_B", "Supplier_01", "Customer_BY", "150"),
("C003", "Product_B", "Supplier_02", "Customer_DY", "850"),
("C003", "Product_C", "Supplier_01", "Customer_DY", "550");
```

---

In my original `database` I am having a table called `operations` with a huge amount of columns. 
 I am currently using `*` sign to avoid listing all the columns in my query:

```
SELECT
*,
(CASE WHEN supplier = "Supplier_01" THEN "good" ELSE "bad" END) AS supplier_rating
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

With this query I will get all the `columns` and an additional `column` for the `CASE Statement`. 
However, I would prefer that the column `supplier` is replaced by the column `supplier_rating`.

Therefore, I am wondering if it possible to 
a) get **all** columns in the table **without listing each of them separately** as it is done with `*` sign in the query 
b) **only replace** column `supplier` with `supplier_rating` as in the `CASE statement`?

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't offer this functionality for a simple query.  You need to use dynamic SQL, which seems like a bigger complication.

Comment: You can use a view if you dont want to write sql every time for this but you need to list all columns separately. I have another idea to ease many case when statements. So, create a lookup table which has columns like `supplier_no, rating` and data like `Supplier_01,good` etc. Join operations with this table based on  supplier column. And then pick rating from lookup table.

Comment: hope the solution worked for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT (CASE WHEN supplier = "Supplier_01" THEN "good" ELSE "bad" END) AS supplier_rating', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'supplier,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'operations' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb'), ' FROM operations');
PREPARE newquery FROM @sql;
EXECUTE newquery;
```

Snapshot:
[image]

Comment: If I run the solution here I do not get a result. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=70221e920826dfb648d6c026ce75dfe5 Is there something I need to modify or is that a dbfiddle issue?

Comment: Please change the table schema name or remove the table_scheme filtering option. I have deleted `AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb'` piece and it worked. Snapshot is added to the solution !

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=fd87234059597d876dea673b980611ca